# How does USB Type-C work for graphics

Tags: usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Just looking at this monitor review...

http://www.digitaltrends.com/monitor-reviews/lg-27ud88-w-4k-27-inch-review/

> More impressive is the upstream USB Type-C port. It can drive the 4K
>   monitor, provide data to the monitor’s two USB 3.0 ports, and even
>   charge a USB device – all at the same time.

How does USB Type-C deliver graphics to the monitor?

A. Are there dedicated USB Type-C graphics cards?

B. Are there shared/integrated USB Type-C graphics cards?

C. Is the graphics card in the monitor itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there dedicated USB Type-C graphics cards?

Yes, but this is not relevant. The USB type C connector was designed to be flexible and carry non-USB signals. In this case a USB type C connector is being used to deliver graphics to the monitor using alt-mode DisplayPort. USB-C also supports (although rarer) alt-mode HDMI.

> USB Alternate Modes, [..] allow for different (non-USB) signals to be carried over USB Type-C connector. At the time the specification simply theorized just what protocols could be carried over Type-C as an alternate mode, but today we finally know what the first alternate mode will be: DisplayPort.

[image]

http://www.anandtech.com/show/8558/displayport-alternate-mode-for-usb-typec-announced

http://www.audioxpress.com/article/vesa-highlights-growing-displayport-alt-mode-adoption-and-latest-displayport-developments-at-mobile-world-congress-2017

In many cases the monitor will actually be connected to an upstream Thunderbolt port, as these will always carry USB-C and DisplayPort signals. However there are some USB-C ports (usually in laptops) that carry USB-C and DisplayPort signals without any additional functionality (e.g. USB-PD, TB, etc.) and these will be marked with both USB SS and DP logos like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Type-C connector can work for graphics in two ways:

1. The graphics can be transmitted over USB 3.0 standard and then converted into a video standard (typically VGA or Display Port) by a dedicated USB video-class device, notably made by [DisplayLink](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-graphics-adapter,3006-2.html) company. The converter chip can be in a separate dongle, or built directly into a monitor. In this case it will be designated as "[USB Monitor](http://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-monitors)".
2. The Type-C port pins can be switched (re-used) as a native Display Port if (a) host is designed so, and (b) the peripheral video device accepts this mode and signals over CC1/CC2 wires to turn the port into so-called ALTERNATIVE MODE. This mode is quite flexible. It can support full-featured USB 3.0 connection AND 2-lane DP. Or it could be full featured DP connection (since the Type-C port has four high-speed differential lines) without USB 3.0 and miaintain only USB2.0. To have this ALTERNATIVE MODE, the host must have a sophisticated data switch/multiplexer, and a circuitry to detect "alternative mode" signature from compatible displays.

Now to your questions:

A. There could be Type-C video cards, but I have no info if anyone makes them.

B. There could be Type-C DP-only graphics cards, but see (A). Not sure what do you mean under "shared".

C. No, there is no "graphics card" in a monitor itself in any case. In case of a dedicated graphics card with Type-C connector (used as a dedicated DP port), the graphics controller resides on host system, as a usual PCIe card. In case of "video over USB" and DisplayLink, the graphics is done in software by means of [Virtual Graphics Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink) Technology.

For some discussion about DisplayPort and USB over Type-C, see this [superuser thread](https://superuser.com/a/1136882/620011).

Comment: it looks like now (3 years later), there are some high-end video cards with Type-C ports. There are some GeForce RTX 2060 cards by EVGA, some MSI and ASUS RTX 2070 cards, and some ASUS and Gigabyte 2080 cards.

Answer (score 0):

- No (Not yet, anyway)
- Yes (via CPU-integrated graphics)
- No

Usually, you’d use an external loopback cable (DisplayPort) to feed the video signal from your graphics card to whatever is providing the USB Type-C connectivity. Currently that’s either an add-in card or the mainboard itself.

The USB-C host will then mux the signals appropriately. To your graphics card it’ll look like any other DisplayPort connection.

The problem with a graphics card that would provide native USB-C is that it needs to interface with mainboard buses that are not available on the PCIe slot – if it’s supposed to provide the entire range of possible USB-C connection modes. If it’s just about graphics, it could probably work standalone.