# Can USB 3.0 be used as monitor video input?

Tags: usb, display

I am searching for a 4K 32" monitor and I would ideally want it to act as a USB hub for my laptop. Connection via USB-C and power supply would be great because I would only have to connect a single cable to my computer and nothing else.

Some monitors I have looked at had USB-C input but lacked in other areas and now I am eyeing [AOC U3277PWQU](https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/u3277pwqu). It does not have USB-C input, but it does have a "USB Input" (USB 3.0 type B) port as stated [in the manual.](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/330661.pdf)

My question is, does this "USB input" port mean that I can connect a USB-C to my laptop, hook it up with a USB-C/USB3.0B adapter, connect to the monitor and I would get both video and USB hub in one? Or would I have to connect the monitor *both* via HDMI/DP *and* USB to get video and USB-hub connection, respectively?

Comment: Most probably it would only act as a USB 3.0 hub and you would need to use HDMI as the video source. The website you posted has the following about the USB functionality "USB 3.0 input for all your devices

USB 3.0 gives you more bandwidth and SuperSpeed data transfer – ten times faster than USB 2.0. With fast charge functionality, these hubs also quickly power your phones and tablets. USB 3.0 is ideal for connecting all your devices and peripherals to your display, and it’s backwards compatible with USB 2.0." - Note "hubs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "AOC U3277PWQU" you are referring to has a detailed specification (https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/u3277pwqu/specs) that states:

```
Connections

Signal input: VGA, DVI, DisplayPort 1.2 x 1, HDMI 2.0 x 1
USB input: USB 3.0 x 2 & USB 2.0 x 2
Built-in speakers: 3 W x 2
```

Thus, it appears you require one video input of either VGA, DVI, DisplayPort 1.2 or HDMI 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

This display looks like an ordinary VGA/DVI/HDMI/DP display with built-in USB 3.0 hub. The hub has two USB 2.0 downstream ports and two USB 3.0 ports, one of them with unspecified charging capability.

The USB section doesn't appear to have anything related to video. This is an ordinary normal display. You won't have any video over any Type-C adapters/cables.

There was one display with Type-C input, under SE questions, take a look into [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1136882/620011).