# 27 inch Monitor with USB Type C connector, benefits?

Tags: usb, display, usb-c

Might be dumb question, but here it goes:
If i have a PC without any USB Type C (Only USB 2.0 and USB 3.0) , but i want to get a monitor that does have USB Type C, does it mean i could use the USB Type C from my monitor even if my PC doesn't have USB Type C connector?

Are there any other benefits of having USB Type C that comes with a Monitor?

I want to connect my mobile device that does have USB Type C and increase file transfer speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering the question, lets analyse your train of thought.

> I want to connect my mobile device that does have USB Type C and increase file transfer speed.

In any case, this will not work. The transfer speed will always be that of the slowest connection. This is called a bottleneck. You can't magically transfer faster just because somewhere in the line, you increase the speed.

Picture the data as a really long train. The train is so long that when it starts moving, the front of the train reaches its destination even before the end left the station. The train goes through the USB Type C connection first at high speed, but then reaches the slower connection. The train slows down, and as a result, even though there is a section with high speed, the train does not reach it, so you do not have higher speeds.

That said, lets look at the rest of your question.

> If i have a PC without any USB Type C (Only USB 2.0 and USB 3.0) , but i want to get a monitor that does have USB Type C, does it mean i could use the USB Type C from my monitor even if my PC doesn't have USB Type C connector?

The answer here is no. USB Type C in this case is used to send display data over the cable, which requires USB Type C on both ends. This is often used in conjunction with Mac Books.

If the same monitor has a display port interface or hdmi interface and the USB C is there as a hub, as long as you can connect the hub to the main pc with something other than USB C (unlikely, but maybe you're lucky), then you can use that USB C port to connect other USB devices. Given that in this case you will probably connect the hub to a USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 port, this will become the speed of the USB C due to bottlenecking (see above).

> Are there any other benefits of having USB Type C that comes with a Monitor?

In your current situation, not really. But there is one situation why this may still be a good idea: Your situation changes in the future. You get a PC or laptop that DOES support USB C, then it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of "Type-C" monitors on the market

1. Small portable monitors with single Type-C connector. The connector supplies full power over Type-C input. These devices are made using DisplayLink IC controller, which is a regular USB DEVICE. It requires special DisplayLink drivers, and operates from any regular USB3.0 port. Therefore, a PC with regular USB ports can operate this display.
2. Bigger monitors use a special auxiliary function of Type-C connector, and accept standard Display Port signaling. (There could be USB2 or even USB3 function over the top of DP mode. See some [more info here](https://superuser.com/a/1136882/620011).) Therefore, with a special DP to Type-C cable you can have this monitor operating, but your PC must have the DP output. Bigger monitors usually have several input options, HDMI, DP, VGA, etc., so you might ignore the Type-C input and use regular HDMI or DP cables. But if your PC doesn't have the DP output, this monitor likely won't work, unless it also supports the standard DisplayLink USB mode. Then see #1.

Your last sentiment, *"I want to connect my mobile device that does have USB Type C and increase file transfer speed"*, is totally disconnected from your first premise, *"If i have a PC without any USB Type C"*, and doesn't make sense, because displays don't transfer "files".